# Cordova - Get array of images from device? (Custom image gallery picker)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm working on a Cordova app that requires a custom image gallery picker to be built. I've seen similar things in both the Instagram and Twitter (pictured below) apps, that allow users to select images from their camera roll, without opening up the default OS provided image picker. I've searched around for plugins and have only found things that use the default gallery picker.

I would assume the solution to this would be to get some sort of array of images from the OS somehow and then from that you are able to build your image gallery picker, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Anyone got any ideas or solutions?

Thank you!

PS. Here is a screenshot of the Twitter app on iOS. When composing a tweet, it allows you to scroll through a list of your images sorted from most recent to oldest, without opening the default iOS image selection dialogue.

[image: Custom Image Gallery in Twitter App]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by cordova file plugin (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

However I am using Ionic Native (a wrapper of cordova file plugin), steps must be same.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file'

class MyFiles {

    constructor(private file: File ){
       this.getFiles("WhatsApp/Media") // Here I am trying to get the photos from WhatsApp application. You may provide any other folder or root folder.
    }


    getFiles(dir: string): void {

        this.file.listDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, dir).then(
          (files) => {

            for (let file of files) {
              if (file.isDirectory && file.name != '.' && file.name != '..') {
                this.getFiles(dir + "/" + file.name) // recursively scan sub dirs
              } else {
                if (file.nativeURL.endsWith("jpg") || file.nativeURL.endsWith("jpeg") || file.nativeURL.endsWith("gif")) {
                  // Do your stuff with file
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.toString())
        });
}
```